# Scraping url with spaces using requests

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, web-crawler, python-requests-html

I am trying to **scrape** url which subpage has spaces (exp. [www.test.com/this](http://www.test.com/this) is just the example), however, while using requests.get(url), I am coming across an error. How can I bypass the issue with spaces so that while passing it to get(), I will be able to work with the content of this website?

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: I was trying to experiment with "/" before spaces since this is the way to bypass signs using regex but it didn't work @bigbounty

Comment: Give the website and the content you want to extract

Comment: Okay, I tried replacing spaces with "%" and it works!

Comment: Scrap means throw away. You mean __scrape__

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
url.replace(' ','http://')
```

The request lib want to have http or https in the given url